# How to remove the previous element using mootools

Tags: mootools

I've added a simple span element before an anchor element. I want to remove this span later (no id on either element btw). I'm using mootools 2.x (and my jQuery chops don't seem to be helping much here)

I assumed a simple $(this).prev().remove() would work but not with mootools - anyone help?

the html looks something like this

```
<span>fail</span><a href="#" onclick="...">link</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

within the click handler callback - and don't use onclick, use `element.addEvent("click", function() {});` instead:

remove totally:
`this.getPrevious().destroy();`

detatch from dom:
`this.getPrevious().dispose();`